# Showing Images on Button through IF Statement

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton

I'm new to swift and the iOS platform in general, but I think I have a decent grasp on it.

I'm attempting to make a simple Bingo game, but I've run into a little issue.

I need to give the user the ability to deselect a number. Right now, I've got buttons that the user will click on to to change that piece to marked (giving it a background image). However, I want to change the image to nothing if they press the button again.

For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out how to check, preferably with an IF statement, whether the button has been pressed the first time or not. I was trying to use an IF statement to compare the image with something like this:

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImage(named:"MarkedPiece") == true {

        // labels for Numbers will be hidden here

    } else {

        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "MarkedPiece"), for: UIControlState())

    }

}
```

The above is the function that all of the buttons point to. I get the error message telling me that I can't compare type UIImage to BOOL, which makes sense. Is there another way that I should do it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set button image for `normal` state and `selected` state.

```
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .normal)
btn.setImage(UIImage(named: ""), for: .selected)
```

and use `.isSelected`

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    if sender.isSelected {
        // labels for Numbers will be hidden here

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That works the way I needed it to. I appreciate your quick assistance!